# I cannot access my files on the other Ubuntu computer

Tags: networking, drivers, server, ethernet

---

I have two computers, first one have Ubuntu 16.10 and Ethernet Card support(10/100/1000mb)-(Laptop).
Second one have Ubuntu 16.04 and Ethernet card (Support 10/100mb)-( as server)

so I've shared files from the server so I can access it via the laptop

both computer are connected using Ethernet on the same local network

When I try to access files from the laptop to the server I can't, but if I disconnect the Ethernet from laptop and switch to Wi-Fi then I can access the files on the server.

So my guess is because the server has an old network card(Support 10/100mb) which is not compatible with the new network card in the laptop(10/100/1000mb).

so guys can you tell me a solution for this issue? is it possible to access the files on the server using my laptop Ethernet or I should replace the server network card or what?

### thanks

Update here is a picture from my router:
[check it out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9jqW.png)

I think because the router divide the Lan's into levels, so that's why I cannot connect from the laptop to the server right?

Comment: "*shared files from the server*" - how?

Comment: Are both computers connected to your router via wire?

Comment: @techraf via Samba

Comment: @eyoung100 yes true, by the way this problem show up when I change the router, the old router doesn't support (1000mb).

Comment: Do the computers and the router see each other? For example, can you ping from the computers to the router?

Comment: @sudodus I tried to ping the server via the laptop but it says "Unreachable" and they both connected to the same network

Comment: I think this is where to start the troubleshooting. The problem can be in the computer, the connection (cable) or in the router (that particular port). It might be the handshaking, but I think there are many other possible causes. For example, you can boot the computer from a live USB or DVD drive (with standard Ubuntu or an Ubuntu flavour). It is very likely to connect automatically, if the hardware is working correctly.

Comment: But I am no expert on the hardware side or basic communication protocols. I think you can get better help at the Ubuntu networking forum, https://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=336

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figure this out, the problem as I thought its because the Ethernet card speed, so here is what I did:

1. I bought an external USB-Ethernet card which support 1000 speed.
2. Install the driver and configure it on my server.
3. connect to the router.
4. restart the router and both of my computers ( Laptop & server).
5. now I can access my files on the server via the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

### SSH

Working within linux I suggest that you run [openssh-server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring) in the 'server'. Then you can log in via *ssh* and access files via *sftp* or use a graphical user interface for example 'Files' alias *nautilus*. At first you can log in with password, but it is a good idea to log in with [SSH keys](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) and disable log in with password (to increase the security).

In the following example the server has the IP address 192.168.0.13. Use *your* server's address. The following screenshots show login using password with 'Files'.

[image: 01-ssh-connect-to-server.png]

[image: 02-ssh-cant-verify-the-identity-first-time.png]

[image: 03-ssh-enter-password.png]

[image: 04-ssh-logged-into-the-server.png]

-o-

You can also log in remotely with a text user interface.

```
ssh guru@192.168.0.13
```

and use the option -X to make it possible to run graphical programs

```
ssh -X guru@192.168.0.13
```

like this example with  'Disk Usage Analyzer' alias *baobab*

[image]

-o-

Windows can connect via WinSCP or Filezilla to an SSH server.

Comment: I don't know much about SSH, but I think it's not going to work since laptop and server cannot see each other on the same network( I tried to ping it) correct me if I'm wrong, thanks man

Comment: You are right. First you must have the ethernet connection working. After that we can start talking about which software to use, for example samba or ssh. (I find ssh better - easier to manage and better security, if that matters.)